# Install New Relic on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: New Relic for Android 3.264.0 (com.newrelic.agent.android.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.264.0)

I got that message when I installed a new relic in Eclipse. Can anyone help me, please :)

Comment: We need to see more of the message including the required items that were not found.

Comment: @greg-449 i already follow this tutorial [new relic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-apps/eclipse-installation),i think all item in there. so i don't know the requiered items that were not found

Comment: I'm getting the same issue: Missing requirement: New Relic Eclipse Plugin 3.264.0 - did you find a solution?  requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.8.0' but it could not be found.